# Convergence and Lebesgue Integration

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I came across this question in a textbook on introductory Lebesgue Integration. I have been teaching myself this material but was unsure of how to do the following question:

Let $(g_n)$ be a sequence of functions that is uniformly bounded and converges pointwise to $g$ almost everywhere. Show that $(g_n)$ converges in the mean to $g$.

I am working with the following definition of convergence in the mean:

$$\lim \int_I{|f_n −f|\ d\mu} = 0$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this just the [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)?

Comment: I hadn't seen that theorem before but it answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is true when $I$ is bounded, either by [dominated convergence](http://planetmath.org/search/site/dominated%20convergence%20theorem) or [Egoroff's theorem](http://planetmath.org/search/site/egoroff%27s%20theorem).

However, when $I=\Bbb R_+$, it may be not true, for example if $f_n=\chi_{(n,n+1)}$ ($|f_n|\leqslant 1$ for all $n$, and $f_n\to 0$ almost everywhere but $\int_I|f_n-f|=1$).